# ASP.Net Forbidden URL with Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, webforms

I have an issue here which has me baffled.

Another developer and myself developed an **ASP.Net Web Forms** application four years ago and the site has been live since. About 6 months ago we moved the application from a **Windows 2003 web server using IIS 6**, to a **Windows 2008 web server using IIS 7.5**. When we moved servers we tested the application again in the Firefox web browser, however, I can't remember if we also tested in Internet Explorer. We should have done.

Recently it has been brought to our attention that in **Internet Explorer**, when a user attempts to hit some of the pages within the website, they are presented with a

```
Forbidden URL
HTTP Error 403. The request URL is forbidden
```

I have also tried to recreate this error on my local computer and I also get an error

```
HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request
```

This only happens when using an **Internet Explorer** web browser, it works fine with the likes of **Chrome**, **Firefox** etc.

I am not sure how to fix this, but because myself and the other developer have not changed any of the source code, I don't think this is where the problem lies. I have a feeling it might have something to do with **IIS** on our new web server, but I am really not sure.

Has anyone else seen this problem before?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folks, the problem for some reason was as follows:

When a user clicked a button on my site which would then redirect them to another page within the site, I previously had the following code to do so

```
Response.Redirect("../userprofile/myprofile.aspx")
```

However, after the release of IE 10, this redirect would no longer work, and instead I had to replace it with

```
Response.Redirect("~/userprofile/myprofile.aspx")
```

Hope this helps someone else who is having similar problems.